# Unable to use angularjs scope into directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm creating a directive in angular that checks the current platform and prints out as a directive element a different input element according to the current platform.

my directive currently look like this:

```
<my-text-input template-name="{{currentPlatform}}" placeholder="name" highlight="calm" type="text" class="myClass"></my-text-input>
```

as you can see, i'm adding placeholder, class, type and highlight as parameters.

Here's my directive:

```
angular.module('myapp.platformSpecific', [])
.directive('myTextInput', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            class: '=',
            placeholder: '=',
            type: '=',
            highlight: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            console.log(scope);
            console.log(attrs);
            var template = {
                'android': '<ion-md-input placeholder="{{attrs.placeholder}}" highlight-color="{{attrs.highlight}}" class="{{class}}" type="{{type}}"></ion-md-input>',
                'ios': '<div>This is template for ios</div>',
                'default': '<div>This is template for default</div>'
            };
            var templateObj;
            if (attrs.templateName === 'ios') {
                templateObj = $compile(template['ios'])(scope);
            } else if (attrs.templateName === 'android') {
                templateObj = $compile(template['android'])(scope);
            }
            else {
                templateObj = $compile(template['default'])(scope);
            }
            element.append(templateObj);
        }
    };
}])
```

i'm also printing out in the console **(scope)** and **(attrs)**.

Seams like scope as my parameters undefined, while attrs as the right value for all of them.

This is what i've tried to add to my template so far:

```
placeholder="{{scope.placeholder}}"
placeholder="scope.placeholder"
placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
placeholder="{{attrs.placeholder}}"
```

but none of them works. How can i solve this?

thanks a lot for your help

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to @Avijit Gupta for pointing this out

I was binding the values using Two-way binding. I solved this changing my scope

from:

```
scope: {
      class: '=',
      placeholder: '=',
      type: '=',
      highlight: '='
    },
```

to:

```
scope: {
     class: '@class',
     placeholder: '@placeholder',
     type: '@type',
     highlight: '@highlight'
   },
```

and in the template i'm using them like:

```
placeholder="{{placeholder}}" highlight-color="{{highlight}}" class="{{class}}" type="{{type}}
```

Comment: If you are passing a string to the placeholder, `placeholder="name"`, then why use the `=` binding in the directive ?

Comment: you are right! i changed it to "@class", "@placeholder" etc and now it works. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Comment: yes it is. I managed to solve this as mentioned in my edited question